# OpenCV accessing the colour value of a pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

```
p = img.ptr<uchar>(row);  

for (var i = 0; i < nColumns - 3; i+=3) {
 if(p[i] == b && p[i+1] == g && p[i+2] == r){
  count++;
 }
}
```

The above code will apparently loop through every row and look at the value of each pixel. Then on confirmation that the pixel is a certain color, it will increment the value of a count variable.

My confusion is in:

1. If `.ptr` represents the pointer going to the beginning of the row of the matrix, how can that be encapsulated in the `p` variable?
2. If we are accessing the pixel's `b, g, r` (r, g, b) values - why is it that we are looking at different members of the matrix? Does one row of the matrix represent a single pixel? I thought a row of the matrix represented a corresponding row of the image.

In other words, why does this work?

Comment: Your loop has a mistake: You are incrementing i by 1 (```i++```) - you should be incrementing it by 3. Your current implementation does not correctly check the color values.

Comment: @Freakyy Sorry about that. I still don't understand, though. Could you please answer my questions?

Comment: There are 3 channels: rgb that's why

Comment: @Asesh it correct you get a raw pointer to the internal data. It's your business to know how this internal data is made (grayscale, rgb, bgr, rgba, bgra, and so on). There are other ways to get the pixel for example you can do something like `Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);` that is more "user friendly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ptr<T>` is a template function that returns a pointer to the beginning of the row when it is interpreted as an array of `T`s.
    Thus, `ptr<uchar>(row)` is a pointer to the first `uchar` of row number `row`.
2. `p` is not a pointer to the row or to the first pixel, but a pointer to the first *component* of the first pixel on the row.
   Since the image is a BGR image, the first pixel's blue component is `p[0]`, the green is `p[1]`, and red is `p[2]`.
   The second pixel's blue is `p[3+0]`, green is `p[3+1]`, and red is `p[3+2]`.
   And so on.

If this is incomprehensible, you can read more about arrays and pointers in a nearby C++ book.

Comment: This is awesome - exactly what I needed. Thanks very much.